# Как сделать чтобы при вводе команды создавалась роль с правами админа

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

Здраствуйте я делаю бота Discord на Python.
Я хочу сделать команду чтобы при ее вводе она создавала роль с правами админа.
Вот ее код:

```py
@Bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def админ(ctx):
server = ctx.message.server
perms = discord.Permissions( administrator = True )
await Bot.create_role(server, 'Назв.роли', permissions=perms)
```

Отступы я сделать просто здесь не могу,
и вот при вводе вот такая ошибка:

> ! 2021-06-30T15:31:21.334383+00:00 app[worker.1]: Ignoring exception in command админ:
> 2021-06-30T15:31:21.335538+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
> 2021-06-30T15:31:21.335598+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
> 2021-06-30T15:31:21.335599+00:00 app[worker.1]:     ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
> 2021-06-30T15:31:21.335599+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/bot.py", line 51, in админ
> 2021-06-30T15:31:21.335600+00:00 app[worker.1]:     server = ctx.message.server
> 2021-06-30T15:31:21.335634+00:00 app[worker.1]: AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'server'

P.S Я использую хостинг Heroku

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте заменить
`server = ctx.message.server`
на
`server = ctx.message.guild`

Answer (score 0):

Прочитать про функцию `create_role` можно в [документации](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.create_role).

И впредь не используйте кириллицу для обозначения функций.

```
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Guild, Permissions


@commands.command(name='админ')
async def admin(self, ctx: commands.Context):
    # Сервер в котором была введена команда.
    guild: Guild = ctx.guild
    # Создаём роль
    permissions = Permissions(administrator=True)
    await guild.create_role(name='Админ', permissions=permissions)
```